# JavaScript form validation improvement

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, validation

I have a user profile form with 15 text fields and some dropdown and an textarea. the scene is that user can input field in profile form. On save it is no necessary to fill all fields, whatever the user fills in fields i have to validate and save in database via ajax call.

for now i am using validation like this,

```
    var first_name = document.getElementById('id_candidate_profile-first_name').value;
    ....
      var status = false;

if(first_name != ''){
    status = regex_test(first_name, ck_name);
    if(status==false){
        document.getElementById('candidate_profile_error-first_name').innerHTML = "first name should only have alphabets";
    }
    else{
        status = true;
    }
}

if(middle_name != "" & status = true){
    status = regex_test(middle_name, ck_name);
    if(status==false){
        document.getElementById('candidate_profile_error-middle_name').innerHTML = "middle name should only have alphabets";
    }
    else{
        status = true;
    }
}

if (last_name != '' & status = true){
    status = regex_test(last_name, ck_name);
    if(status==false){
        document.getElementById('candidate_profile_error-last_name').innerHTML ="last name should only have alphabets";
        }
    else{
        status = true;
    }
}

if (date_of_birth != '' & status = true){
    status = regex_test(date_of_birth, ck_date);
    if(status==false){
        document.getElementById('candidate_profile_error-date_of_birth').innerHTML ="date of birth should be in YYYY-MM-DD format";
        }
    else{
        status = true;
    }
}
if (birth_place != '' & status = true){
    status = regex_test(birth_place, ck_name);
    if(status==false){
        document.getElementById('candidate_profile_error-birth_place').innerHTML ="birth_place should only have alphabets";
        }
    else{
        status = true;
    }
}

if (nic != '' & status = true){
    status = regex_test(nic, ck_name);  
    if(status==false){
        document.getElementById('candidate_profile_error-nic').innerHTML ="nic should be in this format 12345-1234567-1";
        }
    else{
        status = true;
    }
}

if (status = true) {
// made ajax call
}


function regex_test(variable, regex){
    var _result = false;
    if(!regex.test(variable)){
        _result =  false;
        }
    else {
        _result = true;
        }
    return _result;
}
```

Can be seen that there are lots of nested if else involved that irritate me, need some better way to do this? any best alternative?

Comment: For a starter I would strongly encourage you to properly intend your code. It will help your frustration as much as it will help us help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an array of validation objects, each object containing properties `reg_ex`, `field`, `error_msg_container_id` and `error_msg`:

```
var validationRules = [
    { reg_ex: first_name,
      field: ck_name,
      error_msg_container_id: candidate_profile_error-first_name,
      error_msg: "first name should only have alphabets" },
    { reg_ex: date_of_birth,
      field: ck_date,
      error_msg_container_id: candidate_profile_error-date_of_birth,
      error_msg: "date of birth should be in YYYY-MM-DD format" }
];
```

In the validation function, you just iterate through the whole array. That also makes it easier to maintain further input fields which you might add later.

P.S.: If you don't know how to iterate over an array, let me know.

Edit: Since requested by OP, an iteration function would look similar to this:

```
function isFormDataValid() {
    for (i=0; i< validationRules.length; i++) {
        // do the validation inside here, it will be repeated once for each validation rule;
    }
    return status;
}
```

In case you need variable property names from the array to read/write, use this syntax

```
Object[variable]
```

where `variable` contains the string that is the name of the property you need to access.

```js
var myObject = {
  name: "peter",
  age: 46
};

var validationRules = [ { fieldname: 'name'}, { fieldname: 'age' } ];


for (var i=0; i< validationRules.length; i++) {
  alert(myObject[validationRules[i].fieldname]);
}
```

Comment: could you explain little more,

Comment: I am accessing this `validationRules[i]['reg_ex']` way and it works. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any form validation library. I personally recommend **Parsley**.

There's a simple validation form example: http://parsleyjs.org/doc/examples/simple.html